# Inheritance in Grails Spock Integration Test

Tags: grails, spock

I have a few tests that are very similar in my Grails integration test suite (which uses Spock).  I want to have a base test class which has the 90% of the common logic of the tests and then let test classes extend from it.

I was thinking:

```
public abstract BaseSpecification extends IntegrationSpec {
     public baseTest() {
         //
         setUp:
         //
         ...
         when:
         //
         ...
         then:
         ...    

     }
}
```

and then:

```
public class SpecificTestSpecification extends BaseSpecification {
     public baseTest() {
         setup:
            // more set up
            super.baseTest(); 
         when:
            // some more specific testing
         then:
            // som more testing
     }
}
```

But trying this I get two issues:

1. It runs both `BaseClass` and `SpecificationClass`
2. When the `SpecificationClass` runs, it fails on:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: BaseSpecification.baseTest() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: any(), old(java.lang.Object), any(groovy.lang.Closure), notify(), wait(), Spy()
>       at

Any ideas how I can achieve inheritance in my spock integration tests?

Comment: You need to extend the **BaseClass** instead of **IntegrationSpec** in  **SpecificClass** class declaration.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Sorry I was doing that. Typo on my part.

Comment: Okay, so there was typo in the issue description on in your code itself? (Are the exceptions gone?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can be done with Spock. When I tried I couln't find a way to reuse spock statements and what I did was to write a `BaseSpecification` class with utility methods that can be used inside spock statements.

This is an example test.

```
@TestFor(Address)
class AddressSpec extends BaseSpecification  {
...
    void "Country code should be 3 chars length"(){

        when: 
            domain.countryCode = countryCode

        then:
            validateField('countryCode', isValid, 'minSize.notmet')

        where:
            [countryCode, isValid] << getMinSizeParams(3)
    }
```

And the BaseSpecification class

```
class BaseSpecification extends Specification {

    // Return params that can be asigned in `where` statement
    def getMinSizeParams(Integer size){[
        [RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(size - 1),    false],
        [RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(size),        true]
    ]}

    // Make an assetion, so it can be used inside `then` statement
     protected void validateField(String field, String code, Boolean shouldBeValid){
        domain.validate([field])
        if(shouldBeValid)
            assert domain.errors[field]?.code != code
        else
            assert domain.errors[field]?.code == code
    }
}
```

It's an unit test but I think it should work with Integration tests too.

Comment: I think this is the closest you can get.  WIll leave question in case someone can provide better answer. Problem is inheriting the actual tests.   But when you think about you probably shouldn't be doing this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I got your point.

You can pretty much use like this:

```
class BaseSpecification extends IntegrationSpec {

    //User userInstance

    def setup() {
        // do your common stuff here like initialize a common user which is used everywhere
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }
}

class SpecificTestSpecification extends BaseSpecification {

    def setup() {
        // specific setup here. Will call the super setup automatically
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something now"() {
        // You can use that userInstance from super class here if defined.
    }
}
```